# filter data from mysql table between two values

Tags: mysql

i have table in mysql where names are stored in autoincrement order like this

```
     344100.htm
     344101.htm
     ---
     ---
     477201.htm
     477202.htm
     --
     ---
     888999.htm
```

i want to filter out all rows which contains data between 200.htm to 999.htm as last three digits ranging from 200 to 999.

i tried to use like but in that case i can not give > and i tried between also but it did not work

```
 SELECT * FROM  `tablea` WHERE  `name` LIKE  '%200.htm' and like '%999.htm' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will give you required output:

```
   select * 
   from 
      tablea 
   where 
      SUBSTRING(name, -7, 3) > 200 
   and 
      SUBSTRING(name, -7, 3) < 999
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot upvote user2629562 answer so here is mine version.

If data are always defined like in sample, other option sililar to user2629562 is to check **7th** character from right.

`SELECT * FROM`tablea`WHERE  SUBSTRING(name, -7, 1) IN [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];`

Or to `LOCATE('.',name) as dotPosition`

`SELECT * FROM`tablea`WHERE  SUBSTRING(name, (LOCATE('.',name)-3), 1) IN [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];`